# Accessing Calculation History on HTC Calculator App

Tags: htc-thunderbolt, calculator

On my HTC Thunderbolt, it comes with a Calculator app. If you hold down the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button, you get toast that says:

> Calculation history cleared

I was wondering how to view the calculation history. I know you can clear it, I just don't have a clue how to get to it. <kbd>menu</kbd> button does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, the most unusual timing to anwser my own question!

When I picked up the phone. I accidentally held down the <kbd>menu</kbd> button and the on screen keyboard came up.

The up<kbd>▲</kbd> and down<kbd>▼</kbd> buttons there will do the trick!