# How to access the calculator history on AOSP Android KitKat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, vanilla-android, calculator

The native calculator app on Android 4.4 has a "Clear history" option, but I have no clue on how to see this history.

[image]

I've tried swipe movements, clicked on every possible button, and even held down the menu button as described [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19407/accessing-calculation-history-on-htc-calculator-app), but I could not make the on-screen keyboard show up.

Has anybody had more luck trying this?

Comment: What phone do you have? My Nexus 7 running 4.4.2 has a stock calculator app that looks nothing like that and doesn't have a menu button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is currently no way of accessing the history without a device that has a scrollwheel. For some reason, Google didn't implement any UI or touch screen functions with the history, and therefore the only way to access it is to scroll down with a scrollwheel. There's a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24002).

There's an improved calculator app from CyanogenMod called [CyanogenMod Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android2.calculator3), which has a history. (The link should work but is untested since Google Play throws an SSL certificate error on my current connection)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this app later. It's a shame that Google did not fixed this yet after so long...

Comment: Alternatively, you can use external keyboard with arrow keys (taken from the bug report), although it's surely inconvenient for general purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Galaxy Note(1) running 4.1.2, and to access the calculator history I just click the little triangle/arrow at the top of the on-screen keypad.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the volume buttons to scroll through the history.

I'm using Fairphone on stock Android 4.2.2.

Answer (score -2):

The two bars at the middle top of the 
top #'s shows the history. Just tap on them.

Comment: How about a screenshot which would speak for itself? :)

Comment: Based on the bug report mentioned on [onik's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/69604/44325), it's impossible to do that on stock Kitkat calculator. Perhaps you're having different calculator app?